# Barreled topology finer than the weak-star topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I have an infinite-dimensional (Hausdorff separated, non-metrizable) locally convex space $(X,\tau)$ with topological dual $X^*$.

My questions are:

Under what conditions is there a barreled topology on $X^*$ that is finer than the weak-star topology?

If $(X,\tau)$ is complete then is the answer to the previous question positive?

Comment: can you plz define the barreled topology ?

Comment: @Ashkan see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks.  So does question say, put a topology on $X^*$ and extract its barreled topology , and see whether it is finer than weak-star ?  

Or we should consider the barreled topology coming from weak-star topology on $X^*$ 

Can you plz explain it?

Comment: The question seems to be: we have the weak-$\ast$ topology on $X^\ast$, which is just $\sigma(X^\ast, X)$. Is there a TVS-topology $\tau'$ on $X^\ast$ such that $\tau'$ is barreled (so every barrel is a neighbourhood of $0$) and $\sigma(X^\ast,X) \subsetneq \tau'$ ? @Ashkan

Comment: Your title does not match the question....

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any vector space $Y$, **the finest** (the biggest) topology that makes $Y$ into a locally convex topological vector space is $\sigma(Y,Y') $ Where $Y'$ is the set of all linear functionals on $Y$! This topology is called core convex topology and indeed it is a barreled topology, You can verify this easily via looking at the Topological basis of this topology look at my paper in arXiv https://128.84.21.199/abs/1704.06932v1 .

So Now Put $Y = X^*$

Comment: So you need $X$ to be nonreflexive.

Comment: Why are you saying that? @HennoBrandsma

Even let $X$ be a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @Ashkan if $X$ is reflexive this core convex topology is just the weak-star topology and the OP wanted a finer one than that.

Comment: Note that the Core convex topology has nothing to do with the topology on $X$ ! it is independently defined on $X$ (or $X^*$ in our case ) . @HennoBrandsma